# What is the inverse Laplace transform of $I_{0} (\sqrt {as+b} )$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inverse-laplace

> What is the inverse Laplace transform of $I_{0} (\sqrt {as+b} )$?

Note: $I_{0}$ is the modified Bessel function of first kind with zero-order.
$a$ and $b$ are constants. $s$ the Laplace parameter

Comment: Is this $I_0(\sqrt{as+b} x)$? If so, what does it mean to have both $s$ and $x$ variables inside $I_0$?

Comment: @Paul Probably is solution from one dimensional PDE ,Inverse for t like time.